# Should a web service assign users an auto generated email address or let them pick their own?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, registration, email

I’m building a web service, that assigns a private email address to users and lets them email their content to it. I want the email address to be easy to remember, so they can use it from any system.

So, I’m auto generating random email address’s like autumn.waterfall.3625@domain.com and green.glendale.28@domain.com at the moment, but I’m not sure if these can be as easy to remember as a user supplied address would be. And would they wan’t to keep this private address non identifiable.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do these Email ids expire

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh Nope, they are permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these email ids are permanent, I would suggest allowing users to choose their own email id and if their email id is not present, then you can suggest alternate ones as you are suggesting.

Here is an example of how Gmail does it

[image]

You can also provide  **a button which when clicked** generates a random email id for them for anonymity purposes.

This way you give them the flexibility to choose what they want but also giving them the option to anonymize themselves by providing alternate options.

Comment: This is good. But, to minimize user effort even more. I think, the app should still generate a random email address like autumn.waterfall.3625@domain.com for the user when they sign up. But, it should let them modify it afterwards, if they chose to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it auto-generated to save the user and yourself from yet another workflow.

If its something that they won't be giving out to others, they can add themselves as a contact in their real email client.

Also if its something that could potentially be exploited by others by merely sending an email to that address, might consider NOT making it easily rememberable, and instead maybe something like SKnhEyS0.0GahxwXAMrRJyG9j.MxVWO64vTfCuprrt@domain.com.

Just an idea.

Comment: That to me seems even more work, now I need to copy the random email,go to my inbox and add myself as a contact and remember what I stored it as ? It would be much more simpler to just allow me to create an email id like hulkwillcrush@domain.com then trying to remember SKnhEyS0.0GahxwXAMrRJyG9j.MxVWO64vTfCuprrt@domain.com.

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh If that level of complexity were needed for security, a "Copy to Clipboard" link would suffice.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't imagine anyone trying to remember that one. Was just an idea for if someone were to try spamming john.smith.#iterator# or something. I'm a twitch user and my broadcast credentials were created for me, and they're both rather long and ugly, but I actually appreciated that I didn't have to go through a broadcast credentials workflow, it was already done.

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh: put it to address book, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1.The verification of this process can be made after they provide an existing mail id and if the same is available in your domain you can provide them the same by which the user will feel familiar.

2.If the username is not available try to mix up the values from mail and age.

I guess you can give your suggestions to the user from the values provided in their signup form and these days the sign up form is required to be as minimal as possible which puts another constraint.

So  a way could be, get the dob of the user on the first hand as there could possibly a minimal age below which mails are not provided(an option) and then get the username for their mail address after which you can show suggestions combining the required uesrname and their dob (as the user won't forget his b'day of course)